# Accessing Office365 API with Client Credentials Flow

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, office365

I am trying to develop a node application that would be able to access my Outlook.com mails.

I am trying to do it in a way it doens't require me to enter my credentials, the application will know them (user name and password). I am not too worried about storing them in the config of my application.

I am using simple-oauth2 but I keep getting an error. The following is the code that is trying to retrieve the Oauth token:

```
    const credentials = {
        client: {
            id: this.appId,
            secret: this.appSecret,
        },
        auth: {
            tokenHost: "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
            authorizePath: "common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize",
            tokenPath: "common/oauth2/v2.0/token",
        },
    };

    const oathClient = oauth2.create(credentials);
    const tokenConfig =  {
        username: "zzz@outlook.com",
        password: "xxxxx",
        scope: "Mail.Read",
    };

    const result = await oathClient.ownerPassword.getToken(tokenConfig);
    const token = oathClient.accessToken.create(result);
```

However when calling get token I get the following response:

```
   "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "AADSTS70000: The grant is not supported by this API version\r\nTrace ID: 91935472-5d7b-4210-9a56-341fbda12a00\r\nCorrelation ID: 6b075f4e-b649-493e-a87b-c74f0e427b47\r\nTimestamp: 2017-08-19 14:00:33Z",
    "error_codes": [ 70000],
```

I have aded the application in apps.dev.microsoft.com

Added a platform (Web API) for it.
Added the "Mail.Read" permission on Microsoft Grah

And I am using the apikey and secret I generated there.

Googling looks like all the examples I find are to connect is using a client certificate. Is it possible to use the API using the API credentials?

If the only way is using certificates, is there a way I can use simple-oauth2 for that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like I was using the wrong method.

Trying to access using the ClientCredentials module on simple-ouath2 and its workign now:

```
    const tokenConfig =  {
        scope: "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default",
    };

    const result = await oathClient.clientCredentials.getToken(tokenConfig);
```